# not able to figure out how promises work in angular http

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, promise

I have the following code that retrieves user names from the server by making an http call on an autocomplete directive:

```
var app2 = angular.module('MyModule', []);

app2.directive('autoComplete', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: function () {
                //can't call this like so: scope.$apply('getSource'); I get "$apply already in progress error"
                var names = scope.getSource();
                scope.$apply();
                console.log(names);
                return names;
            },
            async:false,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    };
});

app2.controller('DefaultCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getSource = function() {
        return $http.get('/AccountRequest/GetMatchingEmployeeNames?matchStr=' + $scope.selected)
            .then(function (data) {
                var names = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    names.push(data[i].Name);
                }
                return names;
            });
    };
});
```

I'm trying to use a promise in the autocomplete source: because there's a delay in http method and I get an empty array otherwise.  Can anybody please tell me how I can make it work?  I don't know how to extract the names array out of the promise function to pass to source:

Comment: You have to [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) the async http request.. or lazy load it I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
source: function (request,responseCallback) {
            var names = [];
            var promise = scope.getSource();
            promise.success(function(data){
                names = data;
                console.log(names);
                responseCallback(names);
            }).error(function() {
                console.log("some error occurred");
                responseCallback(names);
            });
        },
```

or maybe

```
source: function (request,responseCallback) {
            var names = [];
            var promise = scope.getSource();
            promise.then(function(data){
                names = data;
                console.log(names);
                responseCallback(names);
            },function() {
                console.log("some error occurred");
                responseCallback(names);
            });
        },
```

I'm writing this based on the jQuery autocomplete documentation which says the source takes a function that is passed the request and response callback function.

See more on generally how promises work here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

See specifically how this is extended for the $http service [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Comment: thanks, but i get Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'success'

Comment: Don't know why that would happen but have you tried using .then instead of .success, I'll edit.

Comment: If you're still running into problems I would suggest debugging and checking out what the value of the promise variable is, also with regard to processing the data in the controller I would probably consider this a job for an interceptor.  Based on looking at the docs again I'd say what you're doing in terms of chaining/modifying the value seems like it should work, but haven't tried this yet myself.

Comment: Maybe also do some tests to be sure that if you pass a hard coded array back just using the source function with the request and response parameters works (just to verify I'm at least right there) then we can be sure the promise issue is resolved separately

Comment: thanks, I have it working now.  the names are all loading.  But now the functionality to press up/down arrow to select from the list is gone...

Comment: @Riz sorry haven't actually done this myself so I can't say what you're running into was just trying to answer the question since I'm building a decent understanding of promises.  If you link to where you got the autocomplete code in the first place it may help.